# PHP sprintf weird behaviour

Tags: php, printf, precision

I was debugging a bug when I came across a piece of code which can be simplified as below

`$value = '9611080820001471';
$value = sprintf('%.0f', (float)$value);
echo $value . "\n";`

This produces following Output:

`9611080820001472`

Can somebody explains why/how the `$value` got incremented

Comment: Floating point numbers have limited precision. see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Any of the billion-plus answers here on SO dealing with the inaccuracies of floating point would probably help you out here :-)

Comment: As soon as you do `(float)` you're trading *accuracy* for a larger value range. Don't *expect* any particular result when working with floats.

Comment: Ohh.. I thought it was something related to sprintf..